# Почему не перехватывается исключение?

Tags: javascript

Помогите новичку, почему не перехватывается исключение?

```
try {
    254 = 'string';
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: `try catch` не срабатывает, если код синтаксически неверен.

Comment: Потому что catch ловит только ошибки выполнения, а `254 = 'string';` это ошибка синтаксиса и код даже не начинает выполняться

Comment: @Mike, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Работа любого скрипта в javascript состоит из двух фаз. Первым вступает в дело синтаксический анализатор, который просматривает весь входной текст и подготавливает скрипт к выполнению, переводит его во внутреннее представление. На второй фазе это внутреннее представление начинает выполняться.

Если синтаксический анализатор находит ошибку синтаксиса он немедленно прерывает разбор скрипта, так как не может продолжать разбор и не может построить корректное внутреннее представление.

Конструкция try/catch может перехватывать только ошибки, возникающие на стадии выполнения. В вашем случае ошибка синтаксическая, до выполнения дело не доходит и никакого try в этот момент еще не существует.

Comment: спасибо за объяснения :)

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксическую ошибку можно перегнать в ошибку выполнения и отловить через `eval`

Например:

```
try {
    eval('254 = k;');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```