# Фазы работы скрипта js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

На [learn.js](https://learn.javascript.ru/global-object#poryadok-initsializatsii) написано:

> Выполнение скрипта происходит в две фазы:
>
> На первой фазе происходит инициализация, подготовка к запуску.
>
> Во время инициализации скрипт сканируется на предмет объявления
>   функций вида Function Declaration, а затем – на предмет объявления
>   переменных var. Каждое такое объявление добавляется в window.
>
> Функции, объявленные как Function Declaration, создаются сразу
>   работающими, а переменные – равными undefined.
>
> На второй фазе – собственно, выполнение.
>
> Присваивание (=) значений переменных происходит, когда поток
>   выполнения доходит до соответствующей строчки кода, до этого они
>   undefined.

А также мне отвечали на [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941494/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), что:

> Работа любого скрипта в javascript состоит из двух фаз. Первым
>   вступает в дело синтаксический анализатор, который просматривает весь
>   входной текст и подготавливает скрипт к выполнению, переводит его во
>   внутреннее представление. На второй фазе это внутреннее представление
>   начинает выполняться.

1. Верно ли, что речь идет об одних и тех же фазах?
2. Если да, значит в первой фазе работает не только синтаксический  анализатор, но и происходит инициализация?
3. Расталкуйте пожалуйста, какие фазы есть вообще? И что происходит во время каждой фазы?

Comment: [Runtime Semantics: ScriptEvaluationJob](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-scriptevaluationjob) Из алгоритма видно, что сначала выполняется [`ParseScript`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-parse-script), а затем, если не было ошибок, [ScriptEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation)

Comment: Можно хоть на 10 фаз разделить - это смотря с какой стороны посмотреть. Если вам интересен подкапотник - то js компилируют jit-компиляторы в современных бразуерах, ну а затем выполняют. И в общем и там и там написано верно, и об одном и том-же, только вот эти "фазы" проводятся с каждым скриптом поочерёдно(как правило скриптов же подключено много)

Answer (score 4):

Сам же пишешь:

> Работа любого скрипта в javascript состоит из двух фаз. Первым вступает в дело *синтаксический анализатор*, который просматривает весь входной текст и подготавливает скрипт к выполнению, переводит его во внутреннее представление. На второй фазе это внутреннее представление *начинает выполняться*.

> *Выполнение* скрипта происходит в две фазы

---

Итак.

> 1. Верно ли, что речь идет об одних и тех же фазах?

Нет. Одна фаза синтаксического анализа и ещё две фазы выполнения.

> 2. Если да, значит в первой фазе работает не только синтаксический анализатор, но и происходит инициализация?

Нет, это невозможно.

Во-первых, скрипт может вообще не выполняться, если в нём синтаксическая ошибка:

```js
try {
  console.log(never executed)
} catch (e) {
  console.log("And this is never executed too")
}
```

Во-вторых, все переменные принадлежат выполняющейся функции и каждый её запуск порождает новый комплект переменных. А при парсинге функция вообще не выполняется. Возможно, она вообще никогда и не выполнится.

```js
function f() {
  var a = Math.random()
  return () => a
}

var f1 = f(), f2 = f()
console.log(f1(), f2()) // Они разные
```

> 3. Расталкуйте пожалуйста, какие фазы есть вообще? И что происходит во время каждой фазы?

Вроде как это все.

---

И ещё кое-что:

> Каждое такое объявление добавляется в window.

`window` тут только для кода, расположенного непосредственно на верхнем уровне (не в функциях).

Comment: спасибо, прояснил кое-что. Выходит есть фаза синтаксического анализа и фаза выполнения( которая делится еще на две фазы ) ? Вот только не мог бы по подробней о двух фазах выполнения?

Comment: Ответь плиззз..

Comment: @Topik, что именно ответить?

Comment: на первый мой комментарий. Он тебе адресовывался.

Comment: @Topik, первый вопрос - да. Второй - вроде бы в приведённом тексте всё расписано.

Answer (score 2):

1. Речь идет о разных фазах. В первом определении описывается поведение переменных в фазах выполнения скрипта. Во втором определении описывается внутренний механизм реализации конкретного рантайма. Обе фазы из первого определения происходят во второй фазе второго (выполнение).
2. Нет, в первой фазе первого определения синтаксический анализатор большинства рантаймов закончил свою работу и идет выполнение скомпилированного кода.
3. Любой процесс можно поделить на какие-то фазы в зависимости от назначения этого деления. Из первого определения мы можем понять, что будет если обратиться к переменной до ее описания в var. Из второго получить некое представление о внутренней работе рантайма (например понять, что весь скрипт не будет выполнен, если синтаксический анализатор забракует даже его последнюю строчку).